# 'RandomForestRegressor' object has no attribute 'accuracy_score'

Tags: python, model, google-colaboratory, random-forest, attributeerror

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
RF=RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=500,random_state=101)
RF.fit(predictors,target)
yPrediRF=RF.predict(x_test)
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,accuracy_score,recall_score,precision_score
RF.accuracy_score(x_test,y_test)

    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
```

in ()
----> 1 RF.accuracy_score(x_test,y_test)

AttributeError: 'RandomForestRegressor' object has no attribute 'accuracy_score'

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
accuracy_score(RF.predict(x_test), y_test)
```

Comment: It is giving the error continous is not supported.

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-6b44fcadc983> in <module>()
----> 1 accuracy_score(RF.predict(x_test), y_test)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    
    103     if y_type not in ["binary", "multiclass", "multilabel-indicator"]:
--> 104         raise ValueError("{0} is not supported".format(y_type))
    105 
    106     if y_type in ["binary", "multiclass"]:

ValueError: continuous is not supported